# Command binding in child window

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

Commands are implemented using relay commands. I've made this in it's own class, shown below :

```
namespace Log_Reader.commands
{
    using System;
    using System.Windows.Input;

    public class RelayCommand : ICommand
    {
        readonly Action<object> _execute;
        readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;

        public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
        {
            if (execute == null)
                throw new NullReferenceException("execute");

            _execute = execute;
            _canExecute = canExecute;
        }

        public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute) : this(execute, null)
        {

        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
            remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return _canExecute == null ? true : _canExecute(parameter);
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            _execute.Invoke(parameter);
        }
    }
}
```

In the mainWindow I do the following to set the data context. The buttonclick handler opens the second window.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        LogEntriesViewModel viewModel = new LogEntriesViewModel();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = viewModel;

        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            SettingsWindow settings = new SettingsWindow();
            settings.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterOwner;
            settings.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
```

For the second window, in the constructor I set the datacontext .

```
public SettingsWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = new SettingsWindowViewModel();
        }
```

The settingsWindowViewModel looks like this :

```
using Log_Reader.commands;
    using System.Windows;

    public class SettingsWindowViewModel
    {
        public RelayCommand SaveCommand { get; private set; }
        public RelayCommand CancelCommand { get; private set; }

        public SettingsWindowViewModel()
        {
            /* Creating commands */
            SaveCommand = new RelayCommand(SaveChanges, null);
            CancelCommand = new RelayCommand(CancelChanges, null);
        }

        public void SaveChanges(object obj)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Save stuff");
        }

        public void CancelChanges(object obj)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Cancel stuff");
        }
    }
```

The viewmodel for the mainWindow looks similar, it only has different commands. Now from the settingsWindow I do the following on a button :

```
<Button Content="Save" Command="{Binding SaveCommand}" />
```

Now when I press this button, nothing happens, and I get an error in the output window that it cannot find the SaveCommand in settingsWindowViewModel. But if I replace the button command with a command defined in the mainWindowViewModel it fires correctly. This is why it looks like the datacontext is still mainWindowViewModel.

Comment: Please show where you set the `DataContext`.

Comment: Code please. There's nothing here anybody can debug or diagnose. This sentence for example contains so little information that I almost feel like I know less than I did before I read it: *"for some reason it still seems locked to the mainWindowViewModel"*. "Locked to"? "Seems"? What are you talking about? Please show us a) the code for the command properties in the settings viewmodel; b) the command bindings in the settings window XAML; c) how exactly you are setting the DataContext in the settings window to the settings viewmodel.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of information on the initial post. I've updated it now and hopefully the previous question makes more sence.

Answer (score 0):

The code looks fine.

I do not see any mistake here.I think if you execute this code it should work.

Anyway you assigned a new data context to `SettingsWindow`, so for this window data context is `SettingsWindowViewModel` and there by it should work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

> This is why it looks like the datacontext is still mainWindowViewModel.

"Still?"  A window doesn't inhert the `DataContext` of another window so you must have set the `DataContext` of the `SettingsWindow` to a `LogEntriesViewModel` somewhere in your code then. Or the `Button` is located in the `MainWindow`.

Try to set the `DataContext` of the child window like this:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SettingsWindow settings = new SettingsWindow();
    settings.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterOwner;
    settings.DataContext = new SettingsWindowViewModel();
    settings.ShowDialog();
}
```

...and make sure that the `Button` is added to `SettingsWindow.xaml`.